# How is the general return-based off-policy equation derived?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, papers, temporal-difference-methods, eligibility-traces, td-lambda

I'm wondering how is the general return-based off-policy equation in [Safe and efficient off-policy reinforcement learning](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6538-safe-and-efficient-off-policy-reinforcement-learning.pdf) derived
$$\mathcal{R} Q(x, a):=Q(x, a)+\mathbb{E}_{\mu}\left[\sum_{t \geq 0} \gamma^{t}\left(\prod_{s=1}^{t} c_{s}\right)\left(r_{t}+\gamma \mathbb{E}_{\pi} Q\left(x_{t+1}, \cdot\right)-Q\left(x_{t}, a_{t}\right)\right)\right]$$

If it is applied to TD($\lambda$), is this equation the forward view of TD($\lambda$)?

What is the difference between trace $c_s$ and eligibility trace?